# CSS middle-align TWO spans to the right of an image

Tags: css, vertical-alignment

I've seen working examples of middle-aligning a single line of text next to an image, like so:

```
<div>
    <img style="vertical-align:middle" src="testImage.png" />
    <span style="">This works</span>
</div>
```

But I need to align *two* spans, one above the other, because they will eventually need to have different styles, and the following results in the second span being rendered *beneath* the image:

```
<div>
    <img style="vertical-align:middle;" src="testImage.png" />
    <span>This doesn't work</span><br />
    <span>I'm annoyed</span>
</div>
```

**NOTE:** I did experiment with using *float:left;* for the image, which does work to a degree, but fails when the text is long enough that it requires the div to expand (it does not factor in the width of the image and produces an undesired text-wrap)

**EDIT:** This is an example of the solution that worked for me, based on the answer given by aje, containing a small tweak of adding *vertical-align: middle;* to the div tag. I've included this as an edit, rather than add my own answer, because I'd like to credit aje with the answer that helped me:

```
<div style="border: solid 2px green;">
    <img style="border: solid 2px black; vertical-align: middle; width: 32px; height: 32px;" src="https://dummyimage.com/300.png/09f/fff" />
    <div style="vertical-align: middle; display: inline-block">
        <span>This now works properly.</span><br />
        <span>Thanks for the help!</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: so you have to put them into a container, a DIV or another span

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap `span` under a `div` below is a snippet

```html
<div>
    <img style="vertical-align:middle;" src="https://dummyimage.com/300.png/09f/fff" />
    <div style="display:inline-block"><span>This doesn't work</span><br />
    <span>I'm annoyed</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
div {
  display:table;
}

div img {
  float:left;
  margin-right: 10px;
  width: 200px;
}

div p {
  display:table-cell;
  vertical-align:middle;
}

div span {
  display: block;
}

div:after { /* it's always good practice to clear floats */
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <img style="vertical-align:middle;" src="http://lorempixel.com/output/animals-q-c-640-480-8.jpg" />
    <p>
      <span>This doesn't work</span>
      <span>I'm annoyed</span>
    </p>
</div>
```